# Syntax error on anonymous function declaration, but not after valid statement

Tags: javascript

I just spend long time digging through callbacks in promises wondering why some callbacks are not called. In the end problem was with incorrect declaration, instead of

```
       Promise.when(null).then(function () {
            var p = new Promise();
            p.fail(new Error("some message"));
            return p;
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("success");
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("failure");
        });
```

I did

```
       Promise.when(null).then(function () {
            var p = new Promise();
            p.fail(new Error("some message"));
            return p;
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("success");
        }), function (err) {
            console.log("failure");
        };
```

Regardless of Promise implementation details it boils down to one thing:

```
function(){};//throws SyntaxError
"something valid, or function call", function(){};//no error
```

I would like someone to explain this to me. Why first is throwing `SyntaxError` while latter is valid (at least in  browser console)? It seems to declare anonymous function. 
Same thing happens when I try

```
eval("function(){};//throws SyntaxError")
eval("'lala',function(){};//no error")
```

So can someone explain me why first is not valid while latter is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement that begins with the keyword "function" must be a valid function declaration statement.  That requires a name for the function.

In an expression (or expression statement), that rule is different; no name is necessary because the function acts as a value in that context. No name is required then.

Thus this:

```
function myFunction() {
  // ...
}
```

is a function declaration statement.  This:

```
5 + function() {};
```

is an expression statement (a silly one, but JavaScript is ok with that). Similarly, your example that results in no error is an expression with the comma operator:

```
"lala", function() {};
```

The keyword "function" does not appear at the beginning of either of those two expressions, so the parser does not insist on a name for the function.

Comment: continuation.(); was leftover after removing parts of original code. I removed it from code snippets. But thx, for the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was not working because, as you figured out, the second function was not passed as a parameter - you put the closing paren before the function.  It was causing no error because JavaScript recognized it as a function expression.  Your use of the comma operator told JavaScript to expect the next statement to be an expression.

A function *declaration* cannot be anonymous, but a function *expression* can.  A stand alone anonymous function looks like a function declaration that is missing an identifier to JavaScript.  But, combined with an operator, JavaScript treats an anonymous function as the operator's operand expression.

The statement `'lala',function(){}` consists of an expression (`'lala'`) followed by an operator (`,`) followed by a function expression.  This statement is similar: `0,function(){}`.  `Promise.when(...).then(...)` is also a valid expression, so `Promise.when(...).then(...),function(){}` works just the same.

Comment: continuation.(); was leftover after removing parts of original code. I removed it from code snippets. Actual question was about second part, so thx, for function declaration/expression clarification.

Comment: Neither of your corrected code snippets produce a syntax error.

Comment: That is the point. Latter Promise example is valid, but error handler is not actually passed to the Promise.then() and is never called. I was suprised why there was no error on function that follows last then()

Comment: OH!  Your question is why your second `Promise` code *doesn't* cause a syntax error?

Comment: yep... maybe expressed in indirect way... but that was the question

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer to better address your question.