# Context binding syntax

Tags: javascript

Lets assume we have

```
function () {}.bind(null);
```

and

```
(function () {}).bind(null);
```

Why the first one doesn't work in developer console (it throws syntax error) but both of them work in code (".js" file in website).

Comment: I think its because you are trying to define an anonymous function. Console has no future way of referencing it so its a pointless endeavour, youre defining a function you have no way of calling. If you define it as a variable it works - `var a = function () {}.bind(null);`

Comment: Also I dont think its binding related. Defining an anonymous function without binding and you have the same error.

Comment: @Craicerjack i think you can write it as an answer. But why its throwing SyntaxError?

Comment: Because normally anonymous functions have to be used like variables. If you write anonymous functions you must assign them to a variable or pass them as parameter, unless you instantly call them (in that case they are called IIFE,  immediately-invoked function expression). The error you receive is that the parser see it as a function declaration where you forgot to put the function name

Comment: here an explaination why adding parens works: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because you are trying to define an anonymous function. Console has no future way of referencing it so its a pointless endeavour, youre defining a function you have no way of calling. If you define it as a variable it works:

```
 var a = function () {}.bind(null);
```

Also I dont think its binding related. Defining an anonymous function without binding and you have the same error

**Edits**

> A statement that begins with the keyword "function" must be a valid
>   function declaration statement. That requires a name for the function.
>
> In an expression (or expression statement), that rule is different; no
>   name is necessary because the function acts as a value in that
>   context. No name is required then.

- via [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611472/2618653)

> A function declaration cannot be anonymous, but a function expression
>   can. A stand alone anonymous function looks like a function
>   declaration that is missing an identifier to JavaScript. But, combined
>   with an operator, JavaScript treats an anonymous function as the
>   operator's operand expression.

- via [@gilly3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361684/gilly3) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611477/2618653)

Comment: If you quote some other post, please link the exact post (the answer, not the question in this case), name the author, and mark up the citation with blockquote syntax